# cannot edit and continue ASP.NET IN VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have never been able to edit-and-continue in VB ASP.NET since began using it 11 years ago in 2007.
Have tried on many computers.

Tools > Options > Debugging > Just-in-time > all 3 checkmarked:  [X] managed [X] native [X] script …  STILL FAILS

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Edit and Continue:  all checkmarked.

Unchecked native... STILL FAILS
Unchecked native and Managed...STILL FAILS

Did Visual Installer repair … STILL FAILS

I have never for over 10 years been able to get ASP.NET edit and continue to work.  Is it even supposed to work?

Both my VB.NET and C# Windows apps edit-and-continue ok.

There must be something in Tools > Options menu that I'm missing.

Comment: It works for me when I hit a breakpoint to edit and update code in Asp.Net webforms and continue, although not every time

Comment: Did you have to set an option or something in Visual Studio?

Comment: No just standard out of the box vs